# Is there a request timeout mechanism for puma web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When a request is taking too long to complete, is it possible to configure a timeout setting in puma to stop the request process? In my server, there is a case where a worker thread in puma consumes a lot of CPU and RAM and takes a very long time to finish. I assume there is a logic error on my app that causing this.

I need a way to stop the request so it doesn't make the user wait for a long time and slow down other processes. I need this as temporary solution until I found the problem on my application.

Answer (score 1):

Try [rack-timout](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-timeout).

A Puma timeout feature was requested in 2017 (https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1349), but AFAIK never
implemented.